# Font Awesome doesn't work with direct string input

Tags: android, textview, font-awesome

I want to set font awesome to one text view in my application.
I used it like below and it works fine:

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
 TextView awesomeButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.awesome_button);
 awesomeButton.setTypeface(font);
 awesomeButton.setText(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.heart));
```

But when i want to use it like below cod, It doesn't work:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
TextView awesomeButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.awesome_button);
awesomeButton.setTypeface(font);
awesomeButton.setText("&#xf076;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
TextView awesomeButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.awesome_button);
awesomeButton.setTypeface(font);
awesomeButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#xf076;"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code

```
awesomeButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#xf076;"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code I think this one help you.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
TextView awesomeButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.awesome_button);
awesomeButton.setTypeface(font);
String tmpHtml = "<html>&#x2665;</html>";
String htmlTextStr = Html.fromHtml(tmpHtml).toString();
awesomeButton.setText(htmlTextStr);
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml deprecated in Android N ?

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi yes deprecated so you can use instead Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY); for more information refer below link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT